# Include json file as value of another json file using bash and jq

Tags: bash, jq

how can I integrate the following json file

```
[source.json]
{
  "test": "value", 
  "test1": "value2"
}
```

into this json file using jq?

```
[target.json] 
{
  "header": "stuff"
  "values" : 
  {
    "test": "value",   //from source.json
    "test1": "value2"   //from source.json
  }
}
```

It is possible that the "values" key in the target json file does not yet exist or that it already contains values. In both cases, the target.json file shown here should be created.

Comment: What is the part with `[source.json]`? Are they part of the JSON file? that would make it invalid. Your JSON is invalid. Post a MCVE

Comment: Sorry, it was a copy&paste error. source.json is a json file.

Comment: You forgot to update target.json, and to check it’s valid JSON. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```sh
$ jq --slurpfile source source.json '.values = $source[0]' target.json
{
  "header": "stuff",
  "values": {
    "test": "value",
    "test1": "value2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you redesign the jq call in such a way that if the "values" ​​key does not yet exist it adds it?

Comment: oh ok, thats awesome!